# How to break from a nested for loop to its outermost loop?

Tags: java

I am attempting to solve a problem where I must find 3 numbers which add up to the number n for t number of cases.

Here are the restrictions

```
Given four numbers N,A,B,C, find three numbers that sum up to N, with the following restrictions:

The first number must be an integer between 0 and A (inclusive)
The second number must be an integer between 0 and B (inclusive)
The third number must be an integer between 0 and C (inclusive)
```

I currently have a working solution, however my solution prints out every single possible answer instead of just the very first one which is the correct answer. How am I able to return to my very first for-loop once finding the very first solution?

Here is the link to the problem: https://dmoj.ca/problem/ac19p1

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int t = input.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<t;i++){

            int n = input.nextInt();
            int a = input.nextInt();
            int b = input.nextInt();
            int c = input.nextInt();

            if(n<0){
                System.out.println("-1");
            }
            else{
                for(int one=0; one<(a+1); one++){
                    for(int two=0; two<(b+1); two++){
                        for(int three=0; three<(c+1); three++){
                            if((one+two+three)==n){
                                System.out.println(one+" "+two+" "+three);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
1
100
100
53 
49
```

Correct Solution:

```
0 51 49
```

My current solution:

```
0 51 49
0 52 48
0 53 47
1 50 49
1 51 48
1 52 47
1 53 46
2 49 49
2 50 48
...
```

Comment: Note: you don't need the loop for C. Just subtract A + B from N to find the value C would need to be, and then check whether it is in the range from 0 to C.

Comment: Ah yes I am just realizing how slow my solution is and am switching to the subtracting solution, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a label.

```
      endItAll:
            for(int one=0; one<(a+1); one++){
                for(int two=0; two<(b+1); two++){
                    for(int three=0; three<(c+1); three++){
                        if((one+two+three)==n){
                            System.out.println(one+" "+two+" "+three);
                            break endItAll;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

More info in the tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html